# The Angular application doesn't receive Set-Cookie header even though the server sends it

Tags: angular5

I am sending a `post` request to the server as follows

I get the response and I print the headers received in the response as follows

```
 return this.bs.signinUser(user).subscribe((res:HttpResponse<any>)=>{console.log('response from server:',res);
      console.log('response headers',res.headers.keys())
    } );
```

I noticed that even though the server sends 10 Headers, the client (Angular) printed only 9. The Set-Cookie header wasn't sent to the Angular application. Why does this happen? It seems that probably because of this, my application doesn't set the cookies suppose to have been received in `Set-Cookie` header in subsequent requests which fails the authentication.

Response as seen from browser's debug console (network tab)

[image]

Response printed on browsers' console.

```
response from server: 
Object { headers: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:9000/ws/users/signin", ok: true, type: 4, body: {…} }
main.bundle.js:1127:13
response headers 
[…]
​
0: "Content-Length"
​
1: "Content-Security-Policy"
​
2: "Content-Type"
​
3: "Date"
​
4: "Referrer-Policy"
​
5: "X-Content-Type-Options"
​
6: "X-Frame-Options"
​
7: "X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies"
​
8: "X-XSS-Protection"
​
length: 9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the cookie I was sending had `secureCookie` flag set to true. My theory on this topic is weak but it seems this flag is required to avoid evesdropping. For the moment, I have set this flag to false to make my authentication work. However, I still only see 9 headers in the print. I'll update my answer (as soon as I understand the theory behind this).